# Is it possible to get macOS running in a Docker container?

Tags: virtualization, docker, macos

I know that it's possible to get macOS running in a VM under Parallels, VirtualBox and VMWare Fusion. I have containers with Windows and many distributions of Linux and BSD Unix. I'm hoping somebody has managed to get macOS running in a container.

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/607443/can-mac-os-x-be-run-inside-docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks promising! I will try to get it to work.

https://github.com/Cleafy/sxkdvm

Comment: This is NOT a means of using macOS with Docker directly. This is describes the process of making a Hackintosh image and running it indirectly with Docker...a considerable achievement, but nowhere near the functionality of macOS running similarly to Windows or Linux under Docker.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can run macOS in a Docker Container: https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX

It has **very** low overheads because it's all real KVM nested virtualization.

I have stress tested it and the minimum requirements is about 2.5GB of RAM per container. The Docker container is Arch but it has very low overheads.

Make your own container:

```bsh
# Catalina
docker run -it \
    --device /dev/kvm \
    -p 50922:10022 \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -e "DISPLAY=${DISPLAY:-:0.0}" \
    sickcodes/docker-osx:latest

# Big Sur
docker run -it \
    --device /dev/kvm \
    -p 50922:10022 \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -e "DISPLAY=${DISPLAY:-:0.0}" \
    sickcodes/docker-osx:big-sur
```

Or if you want to fast-track, or use CLI only, you can boot straight into a real headless MacOS command line using `:auto`

```bsh
docker run -it \
    --device /dev/kvm \
    sickcodes/docker-osx:auto
```

You'll drop into the Darwin shell.

#### Extra options:

Visual display:

```bsh
    -e "DISPLAY=${DISPLAY:-:0.0}" \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
```

Add SSH:

```bsh
    -p 50922:10022 \
```

Change resolution

```bsh
    -e GENERATE_UNIQUE=true \
    -e WIDTH=800 \
    -e HEIGHT=600 \
```

Comment: if i run using ```:auto``` would i still be able to use xcode/java/npm to build ios apps?

Comment: `very low overhead` ... `2.5GB of RAM per container` wut??